# how to show the parameter received from objectiove C in html using javascript

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

my javascript method which is being called from objective c where i am trying to put the value received from objective in a textbox of the html. At first instance it is coming but then pagee is getting refreshed and textbox is loosing the value

```
function square(val)
{
alert('Entered value is ="+val);
document.getElementById('txtshow').value=val; 
}

piece of code written in objective c from where i am calling javascript is-
(i am calling this javascript on button's click)

-(IBAction)btnResultClicked:(id)sender
{
 NSString *function=[NSSTring stringWithhFormat:@"square(%d)",val];
 [webView loadHTMLSt5ring:strFile baseURL:nil];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
 webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
 [self.view addSubView:webView];
 }
```

Comment: I have already loaded the file ...so dont worry for that ..just help me in storing the value in the textbox of the html page......

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `strFile` is not already loaded to a webView when you execute javascript on that, maybe you could try executing javascript after web view finishes loading:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *function=[NSSTring stringWithhFormat:@"square(%d)",val];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
}
```